# Facial recognition matching faces

Tags: face-recognition

I have come across many solutions for facial recognition even down to a javascript level: http://facedetection.jaysalvat.com/, however i'm wondering if there's any solution to match faces in images, and for a percentage to be output on how much of a match they are,

I first thought of PHP and ImageMagik, however i then thought of Python as i've heard this is lightening fast at processing tasks like this...

Has anyone any solutions, using any languages, web or desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately face.com is already closed. But http://skybiometry.com has a drop-in replacement. The same Python API wrapper shall work after endpoint URL is changed.